# Unloading appdomain don't clear C++ COM object static members

Tags: c#, c++, com, appdomain

I'm using a 3rd party C++ COM objects which seems to hold a few static members. The thing is I have to reset the static members everytime I'm starting a new run. Therefore I currently need to close and open my application. I tryed to use AppDomain to unload the whole memory of those static members but I have no idea why it won't work. I'm rasing the COM object using `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeByCLSID)` is there anything I need to do manually to dispose those instances? note that I checked and any static C# objects does dispose that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unmanaged resources are called *unmanaged* because their memory isn't handled by the *managed garbage collector*.

Any unmanaged resource must be manually disposed. This is one of the goals (if not the most important one) of `IDisposable`: its implementations have some associated unmanaged resource. For example, a `FileStream` needs to be disposed manually because it's a wrapper of Win32 API calls.

In summary, unloading an `AppDomain` or any other approach won't help here. You're who needs to code to dispose these COM static resources whenever you don't need them anymore (*i.e. when you close the app*).

Comment: How can I close COM object static resource without killing my application? will `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` do the job?

Comment: @maordavid Actually I'm not an interop expert so I don't have a clear answer to this other question. BTW, you can be sure that any unmanaged resource should manually disposed by you in your app code...

Comment: @maordavid It's also perfectly possible that these 3rd party COM compontents were incorrectly implemented... they should provide some way to re-initialize their unamanged resources or who knows what...

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I say 3rd party is actually someone else COM object which I can ask from him to add initialization method to.

Comment: @maordavid Well, then this is the way to go, isn't it?

Comment: Seems that way, the reason I tried to use AppDomain is because we have lots and lots of different DLLs which we'll have to change in order to make it work. I thought the AppDomain will help me to make a shortcut. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @maordavid `AppDomain` is actually the class name to create a security sandbox and it can be useful to being able to unload managed assemblies during run-time... Sadly this doesn't apply to unmanaged resources :(

Comment: @maordavid Good luck solving the entire issue!!